# Замена строки в файле с помощью ansible

Tags: html, linux, ansible

Мне необходимо заменить строку в файле `index.php` по регулярному выражению. Ansible выполняет задачу без ошибок, но ничего не изменяет. Задача ansible:

```
  - name: Update restore date postgres
ansible.builtin.replace:
  path: /home/rocketdata/index.php
  regexp: '^<h1 class="text">POSTGRES MIRROR №2 Version:[0-9]{1,3} Date\/Time last update: [0-9]{4}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}<\/h1>$'
  replace: '<h1 class="text">POSTGRES MIRROR №2 Version:14 Date/Time last update: {{ansible_date_time.date}}/{{ansible_date_time.time}}</h1>'
```

Файл `index.php`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DATABASES</title>
    <style>
    .text{

      font-size: 20pt;
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', 'Times',serif;
      border-bottom: 2px solid Black;
      border-top: 2px solid Black;
      text-align: left;
      background-color: White;
      margin-right: 10pt;
      margin-left: 10pt;
    }
    .head_block{
      font-size: 30pt;
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', 'Times',serif;
      border-bottom: 1px solid Black;
      border-top: 1px solid Black;
      border-right: 1px solid Black;
      border-left: 1px solid Black;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: Gray;
    }
    body{
      background-color: White;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="head_block"> DATABASES</h1>
    <h1 class="text">p Version:13 Date/Time last update: 23.04.2021/24:00:00</h1>
    <h1 class="text">POSTGRES MIRROR №2 Version:13 Date/Time last update: 23.04.2021/24:00:20</h1>
    <h1 class="text">POSTGRES MIRROR №3 Version:13 Date/Time last update: 23.04.2021/24:00:00</h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно тестировать регулярные выражения тут: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не учли отступ в начале h1 и дата, перепутана последовательность. примерно так:

```
^([ \t])+<h1 class=\"text\">POSTGRES MIRROR №2 Version:[0-9]{1,3} Date\/Time last update: ([0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})<\/h1>$
```

У ansible_date_time по умолчанию другой формат, воспользуйтесь:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html